# Strange I2C communication

Tags: i2c, digital-communications

I am currently trying to test the SHT3x series humidity sensors by Senserion. I have their [EK-H4](https://www.sensirion.com/en/environmental-sensors/humidity-sensors/evaluation-kit-ek-h4/) evaluation kit to get data from the sensors. I can plug in the sesnsors provided with the kit, and all 4 channels work fine.

I have made my own PCB which has 4x SHT31 and 4x SHT35 sensors ([DATASHEET](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/682/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT3x_Datasheet_digital-971521.pdf)). The plan is for this to go into a humidity chamber and a ribbon cable then connects to a different PCB, which has connectors to allow the EK-H4 to plug in and communicate with the sensors. The schematic is as simple as can be (this is my own designed evaluation board, and as it is for work, company details etc have been hidden):

[image]

Each IC has a separate SDA and SCL line, as that is the way the EV kit works. All the provided sensors have the same device address and 4 can be read at the same time, so all run on separate busses. I just followed that. Each IC has a 100nF decoupling cap and 4k7 pullup resistors on the I2C lines. The PCBs look like this (the wires are to enable me to scope the comm lines):

[image]

After putting everything together, I am finding that I am only receiving a humidity reading from sensors 6, 7 and 8. 1-5 are not showing me anything. I replaced one of the sensors and still nothing. I double checked the soldering, and it all looks good, I checked it under our Mantis and EvoCam. Soldering seemed fine.

The EK-H4 came with its own leads to plug into the sensors. I swapped the leads round, to see if it could possibly be them, but all combinations yielded the same result, 1-5 not working and 6-8 giving me data. I made a new ribbon cable and still the same result.

The next stage was to check continuity. So using my multimeter, I was able to establish that everything was connected as it should be.

I scoped the SDA and SCL lines of one of the devices that was working and saw this:

[image]

This is exactly as you would expect. It is pretty similar for all working ones, with the exception of slightly different data at the end due to small changes in readings. I then scoped the ones that werent working and all showed me somethign I thought to be a bit odd:

[image]

My understanding of I2C is not great, I am more of a hardware kinda guy, but I thought there was supposed to be a START bit received from the SDA line before the clock would start? On all the non working sensors, there is no start or finish bits, yet the clock is going.

If it helps, here are the 2 scope readings side by side:

[image]

Strangely, there does seem to be a bit of a 'wobble' on the SDA line, but surely not enough to trigger the clock?

As I said, my understanding of I2C is not great, so I may be missing something very obvious but I have been trying to solve this for about 2 hours now and I've just got stuck and not sure what to try next. I may be missing something very obvious! I need some guidance to help solve this issue. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Some additional info;

- The ribbon cable is approx 1m in length, it needs to be that long to
  accomplish the task it needs to do once it is working.
- The scope I am using is the Rigol DS1102D
- The EK-H4 is the master

If any additional info is needed, or something is not clear, please let me know in a comment and I will do my best to address it.

**Edit with response to comments**

I have done continuity checks on all the IDC connector pins and these are all ok (I had done this earlier but it wasn't very clear). I did find a short on the 4k7 pullup on the SDA on sensor 5. This has now been rectified and that sensor is now working. This means that all the SHT35 sensors are giving me data. The SHT31 sensors are not working.

I am now getting some sort of data transfer on them, but something is definitely not right:

[image]

Compare this image side-by side with a working one:

[image]

As you can see, the data isn't what is expected, and it is only getting to about 1.25V instead of 3V. I have checked again for shorts and cannot find any. Looking through the datasheet, there should be no difference between the SHT31 and the SHT35 except for the tolerances, unless I have missed something or misread something?

It looks as if the SDA is attempting to start communications, but isn't actually transferring any data

Comment: No, all timing is generated by the I2C master device, and it should be driving both SCL and SDA for the first 8 bits on every transaction. Since SDA is not moving at all, you have an open circuit somewhere in the path. You need to do some basic continuity checks. For example, are you sure all of the wires in your ribbon cable are making proper contact to the IDC connector?

Comment: @DaveTweed I am absolutely sure. The master is the EK-H4 device, and as it is generating the start bit on the 'working' sensors, that bit works. I have also scoped the pin of the sensor too, and have the same readings, as in no activity on the SDA line, yet there is 100% continuity between the connector pin and the sensor pin. I have done continuity checks on every pin of the IDC connector too and they are all fine. Probably should have expanded exactly which continuity checks I did!

Comment: Perhaps SDA is shorted to V+ somewhere? Or an incorrect pull-up? I agree the master drives SDA during the start of the transaction.

Comment: @KevinKruse I think we are getting somewhere now, I did find a short one *one* of the pullups, I'll update the question

Comment: @DaveTweed and KevinKruse question is now updated with relevant information

Comment: On your most recent screenshot, SDA and SCL are not getting very high. I would say you've got a partial short that's dragging your whole voltage supply down.

Comment: @Annie if you looked underneath the screenshots, I did state I have measured for shorts and found none. I checked SDA to V+, GND and SCL, and made sure SCL wasn't shorted to GND of V+ too. I checked every sensor and they were all fine, no shorts to be found

Comment: Also possible that chips with lower I2C voltages do not have a power supply connected and try to suck power via I2C wires (and IC protection diodes to VCC). Check that chips have power, and also that chips are mounted properly and in correct orientation.

Comment: @Justme please read the entire question before commenting. The sensors have power, I have probed all of them. They are mounted correctly as seen under a Mantis, and also confirmed via an EvoCam. All solder joints are good, and they are fitted exactly the same as the SHT35 counterparts. Look at the schematic.

Comment: What is the exact sensor type, read from chips under Mantis? Most important is the second line. SHT31 AR something, or SHT31 DI something?

Comment: @Justme I have the DI one. I didn't get the analogue version to test measurement over I2C

Comment: Well good you double checked that so it can be ruled out that you ordered the correct component and you were not accidentally sent a wrong one. If the component were the analog one, it would explain why it does not respond and voltages would approximately match room temperature and 40% RH if the supply is about 3 volts. I assume from the scope pictures that the supply voltage is 3.0 volts, right?

Comment: @MCG I wasn't necessarily suggesting that the short was on SDA or SCL. It looks like the supply is being dragged down by excessive current draw.

Comment: @Annie if it was that, then the SHT35 sensors would also not be working as they all share the same supply. The supply is also very stable, doesn't dip, and I cannot find any shorts anywhere

Comment: @Annie except that all chips have same power supply and the other type chips work fine and their I2C gets pulled to 3V supply just fine. Nothing indicates supply is being dragged down, how do you came into that conclusion?

Comment: @Justme Yes, the supply is around 3V. I also breathed on the sensor, just to see if the voltage moved and it did not. That ruled out the analog for me, as the SHT35 sensors all showed  around 85% after breathing on them, yet the 31's did not move

Comment: @Justme SDA and SCL are both pulled up to the supply, right? And they are both resting at 1.25V. Either they're not really pulled up to the supply, or the supply is not at 3V. Sure, all the devices are pulled up to the same supply on the schematic, but the oscope says differently.

Comment: @Annie the scope does not say differently. Only for those ones. Look at the working devices, they are at 3V. They share the same supply. There is 3V supplying the sensors

Comment: @Annie Yes, both pulled up, right, they have pull-up resistors to 3V supply. And if supply is 3V as claimed, it is not sagging. So if I2C pins reads 1.25V then there must be current flowing into chip via these resistors. Which should not happen, if chip has 3V supply connected, and it has I2C interface instead of accidentally having analog interface.

Comment: @MCG - This is turning into a lengthy remote troubleshooting situation. It seems there are a few of us who are willing to give suggestions, but I can't fit all my questions and analysis into even 3 comments (I just tried, but without posting them).  I suggest it would be more productive to do this in a chat room, where we don't have the limitations of comment length and difficulty adding images. If you agree, do you want to create a chat room? If you haven't done that before, I can create one although (same for you) it's late UK time, so no promises of reaching a conclusion in chat tonight :-)

Comment: @SamGibson no I have not  made a chat room before, although it would be probably best to! I am also UK so know it is late lol. I won't be back at the office until Monday so will be unable to take more measurements unfortunately. But this is really stumping me!

Comment: @MCG - Hi, (I know you're in the UK, that's why I wrote "*same for you*" in my last comment :-) ). I'll make a chat room. I've got limited availability this weekend, but I'll add some thoughts. Please be gentle - I've tried to read what you *know* and what you *believe*, but you seemed frustrated by some earlier comments :-) The fact you cant take more measurements will probably (IMHO) mean that people can only give suggestions of things for you to action in the office on Monday. I'll add the chat room link back here in a few minutes; I'll create it as "open" i.e. anyone can "write".

Comment: Chat room link is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94375/discussion-on-question-by-mcg-strange-i2c-communication). The standard approach is for any significant new conclusions to be added back into the question as updates. Of course if someone discovers the answer, they should still come back here and write an answer, even if it was answered in the chat. That allows the question to be closed, by accepting a normal answer (the system doesn't allow someone to accept an answer in chat).